# Android Bitmap.getPixels unexpected alpha values

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

For various reasons I'm implementing a class that can be used similarly to Bitmap in Android, holding pixel data for when an actual Bitmap needs to be resized before getting passed into OpenGL (Power of 2 size thing)

I am using an int[] to hold pixel data, so basically, I my code is like:

```
width2 = nearestPowerOf2(width);
height2 = nearestPowerOf2(height);
int[] pixels = new int[width2 * height2];
bitmap.getPixels(pixels, 0, width2, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
```

Now, taking a step back for a moment, if I create a canvas and use canvas.draw() to put the smaller bitmap onto a larger, properly sized image, and bind it in OpenGL, it draws perfectly.

If, however, I take my pixel data (wrapped in an IntBuffer) and bind it, the alpha values, are wrong.  For completeness, this is how I'm binding:

```
GLES20.glTexImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES20.GL_RGBA, width2, height2, 0, GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixelsBuffer);
```

I don't understand why that should happen.

I've checked the format of the bitmaps and they are all ARGB_8888.  And, again, if I draw the bitmap directly, or use Bitmap.createBitmap(), it works, but using getPixels doesn't?

(The reason I can't use a Bitmap & Canvas, as one would usually use is that, if I do, we are running out of native on certain devices, which are, apparently, very lazy about freeing native memory.  Yes, I was using Bitmap.recycle(), I was setting the bitmap to null, and I was ensuring the canvas was also set to null. Only a few devices had the problem, but enough that I needed a work around.)

[image: This is the image rendered properly via a Bitmap]
[image: This is the image rendered after using getPixels - please ignore the colors being strange as I understand why this is]
[image: Here is a side by side, zoomed in for comparison]

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think alpha is incorrect? I think only red and blue components are swapped. That's because android Bitmap stores pixels in RGBA order, but OpenGL ES expects them in BGRA. See here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html

> The components are stored as follows (alpha << 24) | (red << 16) | (green << 8) | blue

OpenGL expects color as (alpha << 24) | (blue << 16) | (green << 8) | red.
So just swap blue and red component, and you'll be OK.

Alternative way would be to use [GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA888](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/EXT/EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888.txt) extension to specify texture format as GL_BGRA_EXT.

Comment: First, I'd love to be able to use that extension, but I can't find it in Android's documentation or object model. This is all Java code.  Next, I added a pair of images to show the problem. The one on the left is the proper way, with rather faint pixels over the background, the second is the problem. You can see how much stronger/brighter/whiter the pixels are. This is causing a white outline on game objects, and, I may be mistaken, but I feel it is largely related to incorrect alpha values.

Comment: To use that extension you need to pass value 0x80E1 to format and internalformat arguments of glTexImage2D. I'm not sure though what happens to your two bottom images you posted.

Answer (score 1):

Pixels coming out of Android's Bitmap will be ARGB as you have noted, then you pass them into the glTexImage2D, which expects pixels to be in RGBA. I am not sure that OpenGL supports ARGB type input, otherwise you could do something like:

```
GLES20.glTexImage2D( GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 
                     0, 
                     GLES20.GL_RGBA, 
                     width2, 
                     height2, 
                     0, 
                     GLES20.GL_ARGB,            /** THIS ONE **/
                     GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 
                     pixelsBuffer );
```

Otherwise, you will have to rearrange what you got from Bitmap into RGBA before feeding it into GL.

Comment: There is no `GL_ARGB` - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLES20.html . Indeed you have to rearrange the bitmap. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7096786/opengl-es-2-0-png-alpha-channel